# AngularJS injector:modulerr

Tags: angularjs, module

when I have an module error injection, the message is not readable, is probably double escaped like in picture:
[image: Error message]

What I need to solve, is not injection problem (which is solved), but unreadable message, with double escaping.

module.config code:

```
    angular.module("App").config(["$compileProvider", "$locationProvider", 
"$injector", function ($compileProvider, $locationProvider, $injector) {
        $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true); 
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
        //compatibility with angular 1.6;
        if ($compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled) compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I reedited my post: the problem is not injection error, but the unreadable message.

Comment: inorder to fix that we need code

Comment: :(, can be more specific? maybe module config?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add snip of code here. 
May be problem is with ngStorage service you are trying to add here.
use ngstorage as below

```
 var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']);

myApp.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $localStorage){
})
```

Comment: I reedited my post: the problem is not injection error, but the unreadable message.

Answer (score 0):

As i see your module should have empty dependencies injected as follows,

```
  angular.module("App",[])
```